# How to implement 3D bilinear interpolation using numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, linear-interpolation, bilinear-interpolation

I have reached to this bilinear interpolation code (added here), but I would like to improve this code to 3D, meaning update it to work with an RGB image (3D, instead of only 2D).

If you have any suggestions of how I can to that I would love to know.

This was the one dimension linear interpolation:

```
import math

def linear1D_resize(in_array, size):
    """
    `in_array` is the input array.
    `size` is the desired size.
    """
    ratio = (len(in_array) - 1) / (size - 1)
    out_array = []

    for i in range(size):
        low = math.floor(ratio * i)
        high = math.ceil(ratio * i)
        weight = ratio * i - low

        a = in_array[low]
        b = in_array[high]

        out_array.append(a * (1 - weight) + b * weight)

    return out_array
```

And this for the 2D:

```
import math
def bilinear_resize(image, height, width):
    """
    `image` is a 2-D numpy array
    `height` and `width` are the desired spatial dimension of the new 2-D array.
    """
    img_height, img_width = image.shape[:2]

    resized = np.empty([height, width])

    x_ratio = float(img_width - 1) / (width - 1) if width > 1 else 0
    y_ratio = float(img_height - 1) / (height - 1) if height > 1 else 0

    for i in range(height):
        for j in range(width):
            x_l, y_l = math.floor(x_ratio * j), math.floor(y_ratio * i)
            x_h, y_h = math.ceil(x_ratio * j), math.ceil(y_ratio * i)

            x_weight = (x_ratio * j) - x_l
            y_weight = (y_ratio * i) - y_l

            a = image[y_l, x_l]
            b = image[y_l, x_h]
            c = image[y_h, x_l]
            d = image[y_h, x_h]

            pixel = a * (1 - x_weight) * (1 - y_weight) + b * x_weight * (1 - y_weight) + c * y_weight * (1 - x_weight) + d * x_weight * y_weight
            resized[i][j] = pixel      # pixel is the scalar with the value comptued by the interpolation

    return resized
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out some of the scipy ndimage interpolate functions.  They will do what you're looking for and are 'using numpy'.

They are also very functional, fast and have been tested many times.

Richard